# OpenBLAS Warning : Detect OpenMP Loop and this application may hang. Please rebuild the library with USE_OPENMP=1 option

Tags: openmp, openblas, ppc64le

I have ppc64le arch. Can you help me how to setup USE_OPENMP=1 ?

Comment: How did you build the library? Whatever you did there, add that option. Probably a commandline option for Make or Cmake. Please add details on your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could elaborate on the problem? What package are you trying to build?

MMA was added with POWER10 and hence significant effort has been put towards making OpenBLAS run well. If there are issues, then it would be good to know.